# scaling filter fails when coverting size of video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I wanted to convert size of a video using ffmpeg but it fails with following error.

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -i Running-Map-Reduce-program-on-EMR_frag.mp4 -vcodec h264 -filter scale=800x600  -f mp4 -hls_segment_filename 'file%03d.ts' out.m3u8

ffmpeg version N-103157-ge6754d2ad2 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavcodec     59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavformat    59.  4.101 / 59.  4.101
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  1.103 /  8.  1.103
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
[h264 @ 0x3278600] Reinit context to 1600x912, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Running-Map-Reduce-program-on-EMR_frag.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41iso5
  Duration: 00:12:28.02, start: -0.023220, bitrate: 310 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 1598x900 (1600x912), 231 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Bento4 Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 75 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Bento4 Sound Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Matched encoder 'h264_vaapi' for codec 'h264'.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_vaapi))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x3365300] Reinit context to 1600x912, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x3726b80] w:800 h:600 flags:'' interl:0
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x3727980] w:1598 h:900 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/12800 fr:25/1 sar:0/1
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x3727140] w:iw h:ih flags:'' interl:0
[format @ 0x3727300] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scaler_0' between the filter 'Parsed_scale_0' and the filter 'format'
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_scale_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[AVIOContext @ 0x336d180] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x327fc80] Statistics: 9588735 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

## VAAPI hardware accelerated encoder

Your `configure` line is blank, which means you don't have any external libraries and encoders enabled such as libx264. So for the generic `-c:v h264` the encoder h264_vaapi is being picked by default. This is a hardware accelerated encoder which requires specific additional options. See [FFmpeg Wiki: VAAPI](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI) (the site is currently having issues so you may have to try a few times for it to work).

## libx264: easier method

Alternatively, get a build of ffmpeg that has libx264 enabled. Then it will just work. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile & Install on CentOS/RHEL](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) or download it already compiled from [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

---

#### Fix your command

Unrelated to the exact issue you are encountering, but your command is incorrect and will not output segments. For HLS segmenting use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf scale=800:600 -hls_segment_filename 'file%03d.ts' out.m3u8
```

See the [HLS muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2) for many more options.